# Как в golang сделать компрессию js/css файлов?

Tags: javascript, css, golang

Как в `golang` сделать компрессию *js/css-файлов*?

Нужно, чтобы при загрузке он минимизировал их (и складывал в кеш).

Comment: Да проще жать сторонним инструментом. Uglify или google-closure, yui. И gzip-ом ещё. А зачем перетаскивать этот функционал в Go?

Comment: Просто каждый раз делать сторонними программами -будет тратится больше времени. Если например js файл изменили 100 раз в день, то как-бы не очень удобно каждый раз его компрессировать. А так-думаю- прописать один раз...

Comment: [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) или [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) всё будет делать автоматически, как настроишь: склеивать, минифицировать, gzip-ить, добавлять к имени хэш и следить за изменениями. Просто редактируешь файлы, сохраняешь - оп-па-ча, всё само сжалось и всё такое.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте инструмент [minify](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify):

```
go get github.com/tdewolff/minify
```

Предлагают высокую степень сжатия, удобное API:

```
m := minify.New()
m.AddFunc("text/css", css.Minify)
m.AddFunc("text/html", html.Minify)
m.AddFunc("text/javascript", js.Minify)
m.AddFunc("image/svg+xml", svg.Minify)
m.AddFuncRegexp(regexp.MustCompile("[/+]json$"), json.Minify)
m.AddFuncRegexp(regexp.MustCompile("[/+]xml$"), xml.Minify)
```

Выше погружается несколько модулей сжатия, а далее вы можете сжимать поток, байты или строку, например:

```
s, err = minify.String(m, mediatype, s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```